# Why experimentally the Stopping Potential is affected by Intensity of light?

Tags: photons, electrons, photoelectric-effect, photon-emission

Experimentally we can se a little decay of stopping potential with decay of intensity.
Why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of intensity, $V_s = T_{max} / e$, so if your apparatus had perfect fidelity, you would detect no change in $V_s$ with intensity.

However, for each electron,
$0 < T < T_{max}$

Suppose your apparatus needs to measure a minimum current $I_{min}$ to distinguish data from noise.

Then your results will look like this, where L is the *measured* value of $V_s$ for the low intensity beam, H is the measured value for the high intensity beam, and $V_s$ is the real value.
[image]

I don't know how your experiment is set up or what your apparatus is actually measuring, so the above MSPaint graph might not be quite right for you specifically. If it's power, you'd need an $I = P_{min}/V$ curve for detector sensitivity, for example. But you get the idea.